# Mahout 0.7 and cdh4

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am connecting via ssh with a hadoop cluster which has installed hadoop-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0 version. Is there a way to built mahout 0.7 so it could be compatible with this version of hadoop?

EDIT: I add some things due to Sean's answer

I ve changed pom.xml file but I get this:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.
missing:
1) org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0
Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
Then, install it using the command: 
  mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.hadoop -DartifactId=hadoop-core 
  -Dversion=2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
  mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.hadoop -DartifactId=hadoop-core 
  -Dversion=2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] 
  -DrepositoryId=   [id]
Path to dependency: 
1) org.apache.mahout:mahout-core:jar:0.7
2) org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0
1 required artifact is missing.
for artifact: 
org.apache.mahout:mahout-core:jar:0.7
from the specified remote repositories:
apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots),
central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

So I've download the jar file and build it successfully.
How do I exclude hadoop from pom.xml to built the other dependencies too?

Comment: This can't be the right artifact -- the one from Apache isn't going to have a version with "cdh4" in it. If that's the right CDH Maven version, the group must be a Cloudera group.

Comment: I 'm not so familiar with maven but according to this [link]https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Using+the+CDH4+Maven+Repository the groupID is right isn't it?

Comment: You're right, I am surprised they can deploy to the Apache group ID but that is the case. In that case the issue is that you need to update the Maven config to also point to their repo. This isn't found in the 'standard' repos.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the project's dependency in Maven to depend on a 2.0.x artifact and `mvn package` again.

I do not know if it will be compile-compatible since the project has bits of both Hadoop 0.19.x era code (`.mapred.`) which may not be supported anymore, and Hadoop 0.20.x / 1.0.x era code (`.mapreduce.`) which should still work.

Whether it actually works with Hadoop 2.0.x, no idea.

Comment: I still have not managed to build mahout.I guess I should add the repository in the pom.xml but I don't know what values I have to add for id or name.Could you help me with this?